# Custom UIView scaling using CGAffineTransformScale

Tags: ios, uiview, transformation

I'm learning to develop for iOS, and as part of education process I have created custom `UIView` which uses `drawRect` to draw it's contents (Core Graphics + `UIBezierPath` based). Everthing works as expected, view is dynamic and renders it's contents depending on it's width/height. Now I want to add dissolve animation which should look like scaling from 100% to 0%. I have written this code to do it:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0
                options: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
             animations: ^{
     for (CardView *cardView in self.cardsViews) {
         cardView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.01, 0.01);

     }} completion:nil];
```

However, this code DOES NOT scales my view from 100% to 0%. It just makes cards to dissapear (at most). I have tried many ways of doing scaling, but only effect I have reached so far is zooming from 0% to 100%. This my view does perfectly, but not reverse scaling... Also, it DOES NOT scales up/down even if I try to apply non-animated transformation such as:

```
cardView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.5, 0.5);
```

I see that my view look changes A BIT, but not scales to 50%, that's for sure. When I try to apply exactly same animation logic to UILabel, it works perfectly! What have I missed developing custom UIView? Why scaling view may malfunction?
Thanks a lot in advance!

**UPDATE #1** This code makes my view exactly twice as big and than scales it back to original size:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5 delay:0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations: ^{
         for (CardView *cardView in self.cardsViews) {
             cardView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
         }
    } completion:nil];
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an animation option `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent`?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've tried. No luck. Also, my custom view won't scale even without animation...

Comment: @Serzhas You ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: Yes, I remember that I somehow fixed this issue, but it was so long ago and I'm not working on that project anymore, so I can't check the code... Sorry. 

Answer (score 6):

It is simple 100% to 0% using CGAffineTransformScale:

```
cardView.view.transform =CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.1, 1.1);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/1.5 animations:^{
        cardView.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.1, 0.1);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
              NSLog(@" Animation complet Block");
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can try is setting the `contentMode` of the view to `UIViewContentModeRedraw` and adding another animation option - `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent` - in `animateWithDuration` method.

Comment: Thanks! I will try and report back.

Comment: No, unfortunatelly, this doesn't help... My view already had proper contentMode, and adding animation option doesn't made any difference. Please take a note, that my view won't scale even without animation. Just trying to make it 50% of original won't do anything... :/

Answer (score 1):

Swift scaling from 120% to 100%:

```
logoView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.55, delay: 0.1, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
    self.logoView.transform = .identity
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: { _ in
})
```